# Java name clash error, despite different method signatures

Tags: java, generics, java-8, type-erasure, name-clash

For fun, I'm trying to implement a "MultiMap" collection, like what already exists in the Apache Commons library. I'm getting an interesting error with my "remove(K key, V value)" method. The compiler says that there is a name clash - that it has the same erasure as "remove(Object, Object) of type Map". But there is no such method defined in the java.util.Map interface! Only a "remove(Object)" method - with one parameter, as opposed to my two parameter version. What's even more interesting is that if you manually remove the type information by replacing my "remove(K key, V value)" with "remove(Object key, Object value)", it compiles fine. Can anyone explain this phenomenon?

I'm running Java 8, in case that matters.

```
import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class MultiMap<K, V> extends AbstractMap<K, Collection<V>>
{
    private Map<K, Collection<V>> map;

    public MultiMap()
    {
        super();
        map = new HashMap<>();
    }

    //Fine
    public void clear(K key)
    {
        get(key).clear();
    }

    //Fine
    public boolean add(K key, V value)
    {
        if(!containsKey(key))
            put(key, new ArrayList<>());
        return get(key).add(value);
    }

    //KABOOM!!
    //"Name clash: The method remove(K, V) of type MultiMap<K,V> has the same erasure as remove(Object, Object) of type Map<K,V> but does not override it"
    public boolean remove(K key, V value)
    {
        if(!containsKey(key))
            return false;
        return get(key).remove(value);
    }

    @Override public Collection<V> put(K key, Collection<V> values)
    {
        return map.put(key, values);
    }

    @Override public Set<java.util.Map.Entry<K, Collection<V>>> entrySet()
    {
        return map.entrySet();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm I'm not getting an error there. I *am* getting an error with the `put(key, new ArrayList<>())` call, though. (Edit: I tried this with Java 7.)

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps the version matters? I'm running Java 8.

Comment: @TheBrownMotie I think that it matters. I've seen already a couple of compile strange behaviours on SO.

Comment: RT[f]M: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> But there is no such method defined in the java.util.Map interface!

There *is* a [`Map#remove(Object, Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#remove-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) method in the `Map` interface; it was added in Java 8. Hence the error.

Answer (score 2):

This is due **type erasure** process when a java generic type is translated to bytecode.

At runtime the `default boolean remove(Object key, Object value)` (this method is new in Java 8) in Map is the same than your method at MultiMap class `public boolean remove(K key, V value)`.

The compiler sees this, and hence shows the error :

*Name clash: The method remove(K,V) of type MultiMap has the same erasure as remove(Object, Object) of type AbstractMap but does not 
 override it.*

See this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html